# Cannot dlopen a shared library from a shared library, only from executables

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a C++ CMake project that has multiple sub-projects that I package into shared libraries. Then, the project itself, which is an executable, links with all these shared libraries. This is a project that is being ported from Windows to Ubuntu. What I do is have the exectable, EXE, use a one subproject, Core, to open all other libraries. Problem is that this isn't working on Linux.

This is EXE:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    core::plugin::PluginManager& wPluginManager = core::plugin::PluginManagerSingleton::Instance();
    wPluginManager.loadPlugin("libcore.so");
    wPluginManager.loadPlugin("libcontroller.so")
    wPluginManager.loadPlugin("libos.so")
    wPluginManager.loadPlugin("libnetwork.so")
    wPluginManager.loadPlugin("liblogger.so")
}
```

This is `core::plugin::PluginManager::loadPlugin()`:

```
bool PluginManager::loadPlugin(const boost::filesystem::path &iPlugin) {
    void* plugin_file = dlopen(plugin_file_name, RTLD_LAZY);
    std::cout << (plugin_file ? " success" : "failed") << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

What happens is that libcore gets loaded properly, but then all other libraries fail with no no error message. I cannot find out why it's not working. However, when I do the same thing, but instead of having Core load the libraries, I simply do it in main and it works.

Basically, I can load libraries from an `exe`, but I can't from other shared libraries. What gives and how can I fix this?

Comment: "fail with no no error message". How do you know they fail, then?

Comment: @n.m. because after debugging, dlopen simply returns null.

Comment: What does [`dlerror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html) return after `dlopen` fails?

Comment: @PaulSanders This is very strange, but dlerror() freezes my program. If I add it as the next statement after dlopen(), just freezes on that line. This is the case even if dlopen succeeded.

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  What is in `errno` after `dlopen` fails?  Zero it beforehand to avoid misleading results.

Comment: @PaulSanders Apologies, I was doing something wrong. I was trying to `cout` the result of `dlerror()` even when the call wasn't failing. This resulted in a bad cast and broke the program. I actually managed to find the issue. As Employed Russian pointed out, `RUNPATH` was fine for the `exe` but not for the `so` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason for `dlopen` from the main executable to succeed and for the exact same `dlopen` from `libcore.so` to fail is that the main executable has correct `RUNPATH` to find all the libraries, but `libcore.so` does not.

You can verify this with:

```
readelf -d main-exe | grep R.*PATH
readelf -d libcore.so | grep R.PATH
```

If (as I suspect) main-exe has `RUNPATH`, and `libcore.so` doesn't, the right fix is to add `-rpath=....` to the link line for `libcore.so`.

You can also gain a lot of insight into dynamic loader operation by using `LD_DEBUG` envrironment variable:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ./main-exe
```

will tell you which directories the loader is searching for which libraries, and why.

> I cannot find out why it's not working

Yes, you can. You haven't spent nearly enough effort trying.

Your very first step should be to print the value of `dlerror()` when `dlopen` fails. The next step is to use `LD_DEBUG`. And if all that fails, you can actually debug the runtime loader itself -- it's open-source.

Comment: "main executable has correct RUNPATH to find all the libraries, but libcore.so does not." This doesn't make much sense. The dynamic loader has no idea what address the call to dlopen is made from.

Comment: @n.m. It certainly does: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-open.c;h=e18ee398cb0282f96eb534d3a3c22a33b4bbafc2;hb=HEAD#l49

Comment: For `RUNPATH` you need `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. Otherwise you get a `RPATH`.

Comment: @jww The default for most moderately recent distributions is *new*-dtags and `RUNPATH`. If you enable `RPATH` via `--disable-new-dtags`, then the problem would go away, because `RPATH` applies globally (and is different from `RUNPATH` in *exactly* that).

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thank you, you were right. The RUNPATH was good for the exe but not for the so files. I am working on Eclipse, so I changed the working directory to the directory where my exe and so files are. I also tried setting an absolute path for ldopen and that also worked since I actually told it where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a fix for this issue. I don't quite understand the inner workings nor the explanation of my solution, but it works. If someone who has a better understanding than my very limited experience with shared libraries could comment on my answer with the real explanation, I'm sure it could help future viewers of this question.

What I was currently doing is `dlopen("libcore.so")`. I simply changed it to an absolute path `dlopen("/home/user/project/libcore.so")` and it now works. I have not yet tried with relative paths, but it appears we should always use relative or absolute paths instead of just the filename with `dlopen`.

Answer (score 0):

If absolute path was help, maybe problem is local dependencies of shared libraries. Another words, maybe libcontroller.so is depend from libos.so or other your library, but cannot find it. Linux loader means that all shared libraries are placed in /lib, /usr/lib, etc. You need to specify path for find dynamic libraries with environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Try to run your app this way:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/executable/and/modules ./yourapp

Comment: It seems like Employed Russian was right. RUNPATH was correct for the exe, but not for the shared libraries. Setting the absolute or relative path allowed the project to actually know where to look since RUNPATH was wrong. My project is on eclipse, so what I did is change the working directory to where all my exe and so files are and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> bool PluginManager::loadPlugin(const boost::filesystem::path &iPlugin) {
>     void* plugin_file = dlopen(plugin_file_name, RTLD_LAZY);
>     std::cout << (plugin_file ? " success" : "failed") << std::endl;
>     return true;
> }
> ```

The flags to use with `dlopen` depend upon the distro. I think Debian and derivatives use `RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY`, while Red Hat and derivatives use `RTLD_GLOBAL`. Or maybe it is vice-versa. And I seem to recall Android uses `RTLD_LOCAL`, too.

You should just try both to simplify loading on different platforms:

```
bool PluginManager::loadPlugin(const boost::filesystem::path &iPlugin) {
    void* plugin_file = dlopen(plugin_file_name, RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!plugin_file) {
        plugin_file = dlopen(plugin_file_name, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    }
    const bool success = plugin_file != NULL;
    std::cout << (success ? "success" : "failed") << std::endl;
    return success ;
}
```

---

> What happens is that libcore gets loaded properly, but then all other libraries fail with no no error message

This sounds a bit unusual. It sounds like the additional libraries from the sub-projects are not in the linker path.

You should ensure the additional libraries are in the linker path. Put them next to `libcore.so` in the filesystem since loading `libcore.so` seems to work as expected.

If they are already next to `libcore.so`, then you need to provide more information, like the failure from `loadPlugin`, the `RUNPATH` used (if present) and the output of `ldd`.

---

> but then all other libraries fail with no no error message. I cannot find out why it's not working.

As @Paul stated in the comments, the way to check for a [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) error is with [`dlerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html). It is kind of a crappy way to do it since you can only get a text string and not an error code.

The [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) man page is at  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html, and it says:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, dlopen() and dlmopen() return a non-NULL handle for the
>   loaded library.  On error (file could not be found, was not readable,
>   had the wrong format, or caused errors during loading), these
>   functions return NULL.
>
> On success, dlclose() returns 0; on error, it returns a nonzero value.
>
> Errors from these functions can be diagnosed using dlerror(3).

Comment: "The flags to use with dlopen depend upon the distro." -- this is completely bogus advice. GLIBC works the same way regardless of distro.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - Absolutely not. You should roll your sleeves up and write some code on Fedora and Ubuntu. You will see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Prove it? E.g. make a correctly linked `a.out` and `libfoo.so`, with `a.out` failing to `dlopen` `libfoo.so` on one distribution, then copy the *exact* same binaries to another distribution where the `dlopen` succeeds. I believe this is impossible, but if you can make this work, ask a question with all the details and I'll be happy to investigate.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - The first time I came across the problem was in 2008. I detailed it in notes [here](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#Note_for_Shared_Object_Callers). A fellow I worked with in 2012 had the same problems. I showed him my notes and the fallbacks cleared it for him. I was working side-by-side with him and watched him add the code. I'm trying to find my notes on Android now, but I can't seem to locate them. I know damn well it works.